# Align legend rows in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, tex

I am doing a plot with matplotlib and creating a legend for this (see code below). I want the legends rows be aligned horizontally such that the relations `>` and `<` are aligned. Trying to adapt [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16803885/uniform-spacing-with-matplotlib-and-tex) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4066480/matplotlib-numbers-in-legend) code of similar problems, i got stuck.

I understand the basic idea: use `\makebox[width][alignment]{math expression before aligment}<math expression after alignment` as label, such that the space used by that epsilon-expression always uses the same space and is aligned to the right, hence there is free space to the left.

But the `\hfill`-methods used in the links only work if there is text before it the hfill, or if the alignment is standard (left). The solution must be quite near and any help would be appreciated.
This is how the text of the legend should look like
[image]

```
import numpy
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

plt.rc('text', usetex=True)  # needed for interpeting tex strings, but changes appearence of axis-tick labels also
fig = plt.figure(1,figsize=(12.0, 8.0))
plt.ion()

# does not align the '<', '<' and '>' in the legend
# plt.plot(numpy.random.rand(10), label=r'\makebox[2cm][r]{$\varepsilon_i$}$< -\xi$')
# plt.plot(numpy.random.rand(10), label=r'\makebox[2cm][r]{$|\varepsilon_i|$}$< \xi$')
# plt.plot(numpy.random.rand(10), label=r'\makebox[2cm][r]{$\varepsilon_i$}$ > \xi$')

# \hfill doesnt change anything
# plt.plot(numpy.random.rand(10), label=r'\makebox[2cm][r]{\hfill$\varepsilon_i$}$< -\xi$')
# plt.plot(numpy.random.rand(10), label=r'\makebox[2cm][r]{\hfill$|\varepsilon_i|$}$< \xi$')
# plt.plot(numpy.random.rand(10), label=r'\makebox[24cm][r]{\hfill$\varepsilon_i$}$ > \xi$')

# the relations are aligned, but i do not want to plot the 'bla' for this
plt.plot(numpy.random.rand(10), label=r'\makebox[2cm][r]{bla\hfill$\varepsilon_i$}$< -\xi$')
plt.plot(numpy.random.rand(10), label=r'\makebox[2cm][r]{bla\hfill$|\varepsilon_i|$}$< \xi$')
plt.plot(numpy.random.rand(10), label=r'\makebox[2cm][r]{bla\hfill$\varepsilon_i$}$ > \xi$')
plt.legend(loc='upper right')
plt.show()
```

Comment: The reason this happens is because the box on the figure is taken from the bounding box of the outputted text, not from where that text appears on the page. Trying to find a solution...

Comment: It seems to me you would need to add an invisible character, either in white colour or vanishingly small - this would require you to add the colors package or choose scalable fonts, i.e., edit the preliminary text sent to LaTeX.

Comment: @mdurant I thought about adding a really invisible character using ``\vphantom{}``. Sadly that had no influence either. Changing the fonts seems like an overkill. Maybe i will end up adjusting the position manually with either using a lot of ``\,`` or setting the text position by ``set_position`` argument. But i thought this should somehow work automatically.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you need printing characters, but ones that you can't see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution where LaTeX perfectly alignes math, but the user has to take the pain to position it inside the legend. The idea is to

- draw legend box in a given position with a placeholder
- put an amsmath's `array` into it manually

Here's the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

from numpy import arange

import matplotlib
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
custom_preamble = {
    "text.usetex": True,
    "text.latex.preamble": [
        r"\usepackage{amsmath}", # for the array macros
        ],
    }
matplotlib.rcParams.update(custom_preamble)

x = arange(5)
y = arange(5)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

l1, = ax.plot(x, y)
l2, = ax.plot(x * 2, y)
l3, = ax.plot(x * 3, y)

leg = ax.legend(
    [l1, l2, l3],
    ["", "", ""],
    bbox_to_anchor = (0.98, 0.25),
    handletextpad = 4,  # space between lines and text -- used here as a placeholder
    labelspacing = 0.1, # space between lines in a legend
    )
leg.set_zorder(1)

ax.text(0.955, 0.21,

    r"\begin{array}{rcl}"
    r"     \varepsilon_i & < & -\xi"
    r"\\ |\varepsilon_i| & < & \xi"
    r"\\   \varepsilon_i & > & \xi"
    r"\end{array}",

    transform = ax.transAxes,
    horizontalalignment = 'right',
    verticalalignment = 'top',
    zorder = 5,
        )

fig.savefig("mwe.png")
```

Result:

[image]

You might want to compile it twice: on the first compilation it might give You error, but all other tries would go fine.

As to a space between `<` sign in a legend -- it might be reduced with say:

```
ax.text(0.94, 0.21,

    r"\begin{array}{r@{}c@{}l}"
    r"     \varepsilon_i \,\,& < &\,\, -\xi"
    r"\\ |\varepsilon_i| \,\,& < &\,\, \xi"
    r"\\   \varepsilon_i \,\,& > &\,\, \xi"
    r"\end{array}",
```

(everything else the same). This gives:

[image]

Comment: Very nice, the legend looks exactly like i wanted it to be. The only downside of this is that the axis tick labels are now also plotted in the latex default font, not in the standard matplotlib font. The same problem occured for my attempts, probably because of the command ``"text.usetex": True``. Any solution for that as well?

Comment: @Nras: why You consider that a problem? The axis labels are figures -- so must be typeset with the math font. Why would You want different math fonts on the same plot?

Comment: Ẁell it is because for all other figures i did not need to set that option, so the fonts are now different and i want them to be consistent. Maybe an option would be to redo the other figures, but some of them are post-processed and it would be quite time consuming to get that done.

Comment: @Nras: I think for the current project You could leave the different fonts for that particular figure. For all future projects always use `text.usetex` since it gives You freedom to use LaTeX's math. If You're a typophille, use `pgf` backend to be able to set a given ttf/otf fonts.